# Tizen cannot write file in native application

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I am following this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41713258/2330482

However, the file cannot be read back after relaunching the application so I've checked in the Device Manager - the folder is not appearing in /opt/usr/home/owner/apps_rw/org.example.basicui/data/ . I've `cd`d into the `.basicui` directory and `ls - l` gives

```
sh-3.2$ cd apps_rw                                                             
sh-3.2$ cd org.example.basicui
sh-3.2$ ls -l
ls: cannot access cache: Permission denied
ls: cannot access data: Permission denied
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 app_fw app_fw   60 Sep  2 21:31 author-signature.xml -> /opt/usr/globalapps/org.example.basicui/author-signature.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 app_fw app_fw   43 Sep  2 21:31 bin -> /opt/usr/globalapps/org.example.basicui/bin
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? cache
d????????? ? ?      ?         ?            ? data
lrwxrwxrwx 1 app_fw app_fw   43 Sep  2 21:31 lib -> /opt/usr/globalapps/org.example.basicui/lib
lrwxrwxrwx 1 app_fw app_fw   43 Sep  2 21:31 res -> /opt/usr/globalapps/org.example.basicui/res
drwxr-xr-x 3 owner  users  4096 Sep  2 21:31 shared
lrwxrwxrwx 1 app_fw app_fw   58 Sep  2 21:31 tizen-manifest.xml -> /opt/usr/globalapps/org.example.basicui/tizen-manifest.xml
sh-3.2$ whoami
owner
```

my code is the following:

```
char* get_write_filepath(char *filename)
{

    char write_filepath[1000] = {0,};
    char *resource_path = app_get_data_path(); // get the application data directory path
    if(resource_path)
    {
        snprintf(write_filepath,1000,"%s%s",resource_path,filename);
        free(resource_path);
    }

    return write_filepath;
}

static char* write_file(const char* filepath, const char* buf)
{

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filepath,"w");
    fputs(buf,fp);
    fclose(fp);

    dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "AAAMYTAG", "written");

}


void saveExampleFile() {
    dlog_print(DLOG_DEBUG, "AAAMYTAG", "save example file");

            char *filepath;
            filepath=get_write_filepath("d.txt");
            write_file(filepath,"TEST");
}

static void //B Button
    btn_go_cb(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, void *event_info)
    {
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, "AAAMYTAG", "GO successful.");

        saveExampleFile();
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Shouldn't the `data` folder be permanent? Can this be an emulator bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lay in `Run configurations` (next to the run play button) -> "Enable Update Mode".

This makes data persist and **is disabled by default.** Let that sink in. Rather than keeping the data through launches and just uninstall the installed app when you want it removed, **Samsung makes it the default to delete the data and makes keeping the data an opt-in**. This is by far the most ridiculous OS to work on. Never will I understand the intentions behind this, along with having to use C and C++ instead of a proper high-level language. No wonder there are no apps for Tizen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the permissions in the config.xml?
Think you need:
tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.read"
tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/filesystem.write"

Comment: Thank you but those aren't available in native applications. I have `mediastorage`, `externalstorage.appdata` and `externalstorage`